# Can you increment results within a for loop?

Tags: arrays, for-loop, jscript, testcomplete

Is there a way to add results in a for loop, while retaining the previous result so I can verify the entire list as items are added?

```
var listArray = new Array();
listArray[0] = item1 = "100??";
listArray[1] = item2 = "20*0*";
listArray[2] = item3 = "x26*s";

for(i = 0; i < listArray.length; i++)
{        
    _M.Btn(_filter, "Add").ClickButton();

    Log.Message(item[i]);
}
```

As the loop continues, I want the Log.Message to add each array item, while retaining the previous array item:

```
Log.Message(item[i] + "," + item[i] + "," + item[i]);
```

Comment: use another variable to store previous item.

Comment: use another variable to store previous item.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var listArray = new Array();
    listArray[0] = item1 = "100??";
    listArray[1] = item2 = "20*0*";
    listArray[2] = item3 = "x26*s";



    var Msg = "";
    for(i = 0; i < listArray.length; i++)
    {        
        _M.Btn(_filter, "Add").ClickButton();
       if (i == 0) { Msg = item[i];}
       else { Msg = aqString.Concat(Msg, item[i]);}

        Log.Message(Msg);
    }
```